# The main process creates a new subprocess. This subprocess will create another subprocess, and so on until N processes are created

Tags: c, fork, pipe

The main process creates a new subprocess. This subprocess will create another subprocess, 
 and so on until N processes are created.
 Each process will discuss with his child using a pipe channel.
 The main process (the initial one) will generate a random number between 1000 and 10000   and will start the game.
The game will start after all the processes are created.
Each process will subtract a random value (between 10 and 20) and sends the new number to his child.
The child will perform the same operation and send the number further.
The game ends when the number reaches the last child. This process will only print the received number.

I have tried this:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int n;
    int c;
    int p1[2];
    int p2[2];

    if ( fork() > 0 ) {
        if ( n > 10000 )
            n = rand() % 10000 + 1;
        write(p2[0], &n, sizeof(int));
        read(p1[1], &n, sizeof(int));
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        if ( fork() == 0 ) {
            n = read(p2[1], &n, sizeof(int));
            if ( c > 20 ) {
                c = rand() % 20 + 1;
            }
            n = n - c;
            write(p1[0], &n, sizeof(int));
        }
    }
    printf("%d", n);
}
```

But i realized I am going around in circle as the output is always the same number, no matter how many processes I am using and that in fact I am actually creating N children instead of creating a child, then a child of the child, and so on.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: There seems to be so much wrong with your code, that this is too broad question for SO. For starters, initialize variables before using them...

Comment: Also, note that fork returns twice, in two processes (almost) at the same time, with different return value. You're missing handling that completely (not to mention the third possibility, failure and return value -1 and no new process).

Answer (score 0):

One error I see is that fork is not a variable, it is a function, more specifically a syscall. But, you use it as a variable.

You should be checking f in your if statements, and not checking the address of a function in the standard library

Comment: stop checking fork() and start checking f is my suggestion.

Comment: Ok I did that. It still doesn't work properly. It just prints the same number multiple times. But thank you for that suggestion I am sure it will be of use in the future.